# How to map through nested values from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React Hooks to access the Covid-19 data from [this API.](https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/jhucsse) So far, I have successfully accessed: `country and province`. But when I came at the confirmed, and death cases which are under the `stats` I couldn't access those data

- The problem seems to be at the API data function where I get an error that doesn't allow me to use a dot at the => `stats.confirmed`

Here is my current code for the API data:

```
import React from "react";
import { useFetch } from "./Hooks";

function Data() {
   const [data, loading] = useFetch("https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/jhucsse");

   return (
      <>
         {loading ? (
         "Loading..."
         ) : (
         <table>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <th>Province</th>
                  <th>Country</th>
                  <th>Confirmed Cases</th>
                  <th>Recovered</th>
               </tr>

               {data.map(({ country, province, stats.confirmed }) => (
               <tr>
                  <td>{province ? province : 'No province'}</td>
                  <td>{country}</td>
                  <td>{stats.confirmed}</td>
               </tr>
               ))}
            </tbody>
         </table>
         )}
      </>
   );
}

export default Data;
```

And this is the code for the Hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function useFetch(url) {
   const [data, setData] = useState([]);
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

   async function fetchUrl() {
     const response = await fetch(url);
     const json = await response.json();

     setData(json);
     setLoading(false);
   }

   useEffect(() => {
     fetchUrl();
   }, []);

   return [data, loading];
}

export { useFetch };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the stats.confirmed from the object and just fetch stats. Now you will be able to access all the other properties from the

Stats object :

```
  "stats":{
      "confirmed":3,
      "deaths":0,
      "recovered":3
    },
```

Code:

```
 {data.map(({ country, province, stats }) => (
               <tr>
                  <td>{province ? province : 'No province'}</td>
                  <td>{country}</td>
                  <td>{stats.confirmed}</td>
               </tr>
               ))}
```